# How to create sourcemaps for concatenated files

Tags: node.js, algorithm, concatenation, source-maps

I want to concatenate a bunch of different files of a single type into one large file. For example, many javascript files into one large file, many css files down to one etc. I want to create a sourcemap of the files pre concatenation, but I do not know where to start. I am working in Node, but I am also open to solutions in other environments.

I know there are tools that can do this, but they seem to be on a language by language basis (uglifyjs, cssmin or whatever its called these days), but I want a tool that is not language specific.

Also, I would like to define how the files are bound. For example, in javascript I want to give each file its own closure with an IIFE. Such as:

```
(function () {
// File
}());
```

I can also think of other wrappers I would like to implement for different files.

Here are my options as I see it right now. However, I don't know which is best or how to start any of them.

1. Find a module that does this (I'm working in a Node.js environment)
2. Create an algorithm with Mozilla's [source-map](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map) module. For that I also see a couple options.

   1. Only map each line to the new line location
   2. Map every single character to the new location
   3. Map every word to its new location (this options seems way out of scope)
3. Don't even worry about source maps

What do you guys think about these options. I've already tried options 2.1 and 2.2, but the solution seemed way too complicated for a concatenation algorithm and it did not perform perfectly in the Google Chrome browser tools.

Comment: Have you tried creating an "index map"?  It's a sourcemap that aggregates other sourcemaps, meaning you don't need to rewrite any locations.  I don't have experience, but it sounds like what you want.  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U1RGAehQwRypUTovF1KRlpiOFze0b-_2gc6fAH0KY0k/edit#heading=h.535es3xeprgt

Answer (score 1):

I implemented code without any dependencies like this:

```
export interface SourceMap {
    version: number; // always 3
    file?: string;
    sourceRoot?: string;
    sources: string[];
    sourcesContent?: string[];
    names?: string[];
    mappings: string | Buffer;
}

const emptySourceMap: SourceMap = { version: 3, sources: [], mappings: new Buffer(0) }

var charToInteger = new Buffer(256);
var integerToChar = new Buffer(64);

charToInteger.fill(255);

'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/='.split('').forEach((char, i) => {
    charToInteger[char.charCodeAt(0)] = i;
    integerToChar[i] = char.charCodeAt(0);
});

class DynamicBuffer {
    buffer: Buffer;
    size: number;

    constructor() {
        this.buffer = new Buffer(512);
        this.size = 0;
    }

    ensureCapacity(capacity: number) {
        if (this.buffer.length >= capacity)
            return;
        let oldBuffer = this.buffer;
        this.buffer = new Buffer(Math.max(oldBuffer.length * 2, capacity));
        oldBuffer.copy(this.buffer);
    }

    addByte(b: number) {
        this.ensureCapacity(this.size + 1);
        this.buffer[this.size++] = b;
    }

    addVLQ(num: number) {
        var clamped: number;

        if (num < 0) {
            num = (-num << 1) | 1;
        } else {
            num <<= 1;
        }

        do {
            clamped = num & 31;
            num >>= 5;

            if (num > 0) {
                clamped |= 32;
            }

            this.addByte(integerToChar[clamped]);
        } while (num > 0);
    }

    addString(s: string) {
        let l = Buffer.byteLength(s);
        this.ensureCapacity(this.size + l);
        this.buffer.write(s, this.size);
        this.size += l;
    }

    addBuffer(b: Buffer) {
        this.ensureCapacity(this.size + b.length);
        b.copy(this.buffer, this.size);
        this.size += b.length;
    }

    toBuffer(): Buffer {
        return this.buffer.slice(0, this.size);
    }
}

function countNL(b: Buffer): number {
    let res = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        if (b[i] === 10) res++;
    }
    return res;
}

export class SourceMapBuilder {
    outputBuffer: DynamicBuffer;
    sources: string[];
    mappings: DynamicBuffer;
    lastSourceIndex = 0;
    lastSourceLine = 0;
    lastSourceCol = 0;
    constructor() {
        this.outputBuffer = new DynamicBuffer();
        this.mappings = new DynamicBuffer();
        this.sources = [];
    }

    addLine(text: string) {
        this.outputBuffer.addString(text);
        this.outputBuffer.addByte(10);
        this.mappings.addByte(59); // ;
    }

    addSource(content: Buffer, sourceMap?: SourceMap) {
        if (sourceMap == null) sourceMap = emptySourceMap;
        this.outputBuffer.addBuffer(content);
        let sourceLines = countNL(content);
        if (content.length > 0 && content[content.length - 1] !== 10) {
            sourceLines++;
            this.outputBuffer.addByte(10);
        }
        let sourceRemap = [];
        sourceMap.sources.forEach((v) => {
            let pos = this.sources.indexOf(v);
            if (pos < 0) {
                pos = this.sources.length;
                this.sources.push(v);
            }
            sourceRemap.push(pos);
        });
        let lastOutputCol = 0;
        let inputMappings = (typeof sourceMap.mappings === "string") ? new Buffer(<string>sourceMap.mappings) : <Buffer>sourceMap.mappings;
        let outputLine = 0;
        let ip = 0;
        let inOutputCol = 0;
        let inSourceIndex = 0;
        let inSourceLine = 0;
        let inSourceCol = 0;
        let shift = 0;
        let value = 0;
        let valpos = 0;
        const commit = () => {
            if (valpos === 0) return;
            this.mappings.addVLQ(inOutputCol - lastOutputCol);
            lastOutputCol = inOutputCol;
            if (valpos === 1) {
                valpos = 0;
                return;
            }
            let outSourceIndex = sourceRemap[inSourceIndex];
            this.mappings.addVLQ(outSourceIndex - this.lastSourceIndex);
            this.lastSourceIndex = outSourceIndex;
            this.mappings.addVLQ(inSourceLine - this.lastSourceLine);
            this.lastSourceLine = inSourceLine;
            this.mappings.addVLQ(inSourceCol - this.lastSourceCol);
            this.lastSourceCol = inSourceCol;
            valpos = 0;
        }
        while (ip < inputMappings.length) {
            let b = inputMappings[ip++];
            if (b === 59) { // ;
                commit();
                this.mappings.addByte(59);
                inOutputCol = 0;
                lastOutputCol = 0;
                outputLine++;
            } else if (b === 44) { // ,
                commit();
                this.mappings.addByte(44);
            } else {
                b = charToInteger[b];
                if (b === 255) throw new Error("Invalid sourceMap");
                value += (b & 31) << shift;
                if (b & 32) {
                    shift += 5;
                } else {
                    let shouldNegate = value & 1;
                    value >>= 1;
                    if (shouldNegate) value = -value;
                    switch (valpos) {
                        case 0: inOutputCol += value; break;
                        case 1: inSourceIndex += value; break;
                        case 2: inSourceLine += value; break;
                        case 3: inSourceCol += value; break;
                    }
                    valpos++;
                    value = shift = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        commit();
        while (outputLine < sourceLines) {
            this.mappings.addByte(59);
            outputLine++;
        }
    }

    toContent(): Buffer {
        return this.outputBuffer.toBuffer();
    }

    toSourceMap(sourceRoot?: string): Buffer {
        return new Buffer(JSON.stringify({ version: 3, sourceRoot, sources: this.sources, mappings: this.mappings.toBuffer().toString() }));
    }
}
```

I, at first, implemented "index map" from that spec, only to find out that it is not supported by any browser.

Another project that could be useful to look at is [magic string](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/magic-string).